# How can i call a packages function with an stored PL/SQL procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say i have a package with three functions in it. then i create a stored procedure in PL/SQL. How can i call the package "test_pkg" from this procedure and represent the result from the functions?

Comment: You call a procedure/function in a package, not the package itself.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us what you've got so far and we should be able to point the way.

Comment: Ok so if i have function F_test3 that stores the result from the others function. Can i just call the functions in a stored procedure outside the package like this?

procedure test
as
begin
F_test3;

Comment: You call it with the `package_name.function/procedure_name` qualifier. Look at [Oracle documentation for more details](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_packages.htm#i1006378)

Comment: Must the stored procedure be in the specifikation and body?

Comment: you can declare the stored proc only in package body, in which case it isn't accessible anywhere but inside the package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how I'd do it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test_pack IS
  FUNCTION foobar RETURN varchar2;
  FUNCTION foo RETURN varchar2;
  FUNCTION bar RETURN varchar2; 
END test_pack;  

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test_pack IS
 FUNCTION foobar RETURN varchar2 IS
   BEGIN
    return 'star';
  END foobar;
  FUNCTION foo RETURN varchar2 IS
  BEGIN
    return 'foo';
  END foo;
  FUNCTION bar RETURN varchar2 IS
  BEGIN
    return 'bar';
  END bar;
END test_pack;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_the_pack IS
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('foobar returns: ' || test_pack.foobar());
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('foo returns: ' || test_pack.foo());
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('bar returns: ' || test_pack.bar());

END test_the_pack;
```